# how can I export object position info from blender to text file?

Tags: scripting, export, add-on

how can I export objects position information from blender to a text file for every frame of an animation?

Comment: Same question as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/91901/2217), but sadly not answered.

Answer (score 1):

This will write the location x,y and z values of the active object(`bpy.context.object`) at every frame starting from the start frame and finishing with the end frame set in the render settings under Dimensions section, Frame Range. You can change that by changing the for loop's condition. You can format the output as you need as well, just keep in mind you need to convert values you wish to output to strings.

```
import bpy

file = open("C:\\SomeDirectoryBlenderHasPermissionToAccess\\SomeFile.txt", 'w')
scene = bpy.context.scene
loc = bpy.context.object.location
for frames in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end+1):
    scene.frame_set(frames)
    file.write('Loacton at frame '+str(frames)+':('
    +str(loc.x)+', '+str(loc.y)+', '+str(loc.z)+')\n')
file.close()
```

If you needed to run it for all objects in the scene you would need a loop within a loop:

```
...

for every_object in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    for every_frame in range(scene.frame_start, scene.frame_end+1):
        scene.frame_set(every_frame)
        loc = every_object.location
        file.write('Loacton at frame '+str(every_frame)+':('
        +str(loc.x)+', '+str(loc.y)+', '+str(loc.z)+')\n')

...
```

You can find more info on working with strings [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_string.asp). [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/python/) is a wonderful resource in general when learning Python.

[Blender Python documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/#blender-python-documentation) is usefull as well especially the search function there.

One more extremely useful place to learn is Blender itself. There are some very useful examples that come with Blender here: 
[image]

Also auto complete function(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>) is extremely useful in the Python Console:
[image]

Comment: Martin Z how would I configure that to output more info for each object in a scene? can the order of the output be controlled,

Comment: The general idea would be only a few steps: 1. Learn Python. 2. Learn bpy API. 3. Add the functionality needed using your newly obtained skills. :D I think there are many ways to sort the output. You would need to be more specific. See the links I added to the answer.

Comment: The drawback to using `frame_set` is that it updates the scene, that can get expensive for large scenes.

Answer (score 1):

We can read blenders animation data, which allows us to then write that data to a file.

First step is to get the animation data that you want. There is an fcurve for every animated value, these can be found in `obj.animation_data.action.fcurves`. We can search the list of [fcurves](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ActionFCurves.html) to get the curve/s we want. Each curve can also give us the value at a specific frame using [`fcurve.evaluate(frame)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FCurve.html#bpy.types.FCurve.evaluate). We then format that data as we write it to a file.

The index used with `fcurve.find` is based on 0=X, 1=Y, 2=Z.

```
import bpy

scn = bpy.context.scene
obj = bpy.context.object

x_curve = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('location', index=0)
y_curve = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('location', index=1)
z_curve = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves.find('location', index=2)

with open('data_out.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for f in range(scn.frame_start, scn.frame_end):
        x_pos = x_curve.evaluate(f)
        y_pos = y_curve.evaluate(f)
        z_pos = z_curve.evaluate(f)
        out_file.write('{},{:.3f},{:.3f},{:.3f}\n'.format(f,x_pos,y_pos,z_pos))
```

Comment: Yep, that seems like a lot more elegant way.