# Extract object coordinates on from Keyframes and save in external file

Tags: python, animation, keyframes, coordinates

I wish to create the animation of a robot on Blender and simulate the same animation in Webots to check for feasibility. For this, I'm thinking of extracting coordinate data from all objects in the scene into an external file ('.csv', for e.g.) using a python script. I wanted to create a simple scene initially and followed the tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fDS3xKqrLJo to change cube position and create keyframes.

I'm not sure how to get the coordinate data and save them on an external file. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39677/how-do-you-get-an-objects-position-and-rotation-through-script, also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118116/3710

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, @p2or